# Can't stringify an array-of-objects variable in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, stringify

As you can see in the picture, `steppedJobDataState` is not empty. But x = stringified `steppedJobDataState`, and yet logging that shows an empty set of arrays.

I'm doing this because I need to use localStorage, but I'm just sending it empty arrays and I have no idea why.

```
const [steppedJobDataState, setSteppedJobDataState] = useState([]); 
let x = JSON.stringify(steppedJobDataState)
//cc = console.log
cc(steppedJobDataState)
cc(x)
```

[image: Console Log]

... Full content of the state:

[image: Full array data]

More of the code:

```
function Career() {

    const [linearJobDataState, setLinearJobDataState] = useState([]);
    const [steppedJobDataState, setSteppedJobDataState] = useState([]); //     
    cc(steppedJobDataState)
    cc(x)


    return (
      <>
          <FormContainer
              linearJobDataState = {linearJobDataState}
              setLinearJobDataState = {setLinearJobDataState}
              steppedJobDataState = {steppedJobDataState}
              setSteppedJobDataState = {setSteppedJobDataState}
          />
          <br />

          <LinearGraph
              linearJobDataState = {linearJobDataState}
              setLinearJobDataState = {setLinearJobDataState}
          />

          <SteppedGraph
              steppedJobDataState = {steppedJobDataState}
              setSteppedJobDataState = {setSteppedJobDataState}
          />
      </>
    );
}

export default Career;
```

And

```
export function handleSteppedJobSubmission(steppedJobDataState, setSteppedJobDataState){
    let jobData = setSteppedData();
    jobData = checkSteppedData(jobData);

    if (jobData[0].pass === true) {
        jobData = runCalculationsOnSteppedData(jobData);
        updateSteppedJobDataState(jobData, steppedJobDataState, setSteppedJobDataState);
    }
}


function setSteppedData(){
    let jobDataToBeReturned = [];
    jobDataToBeReturned.jobTitle = document.querySelector('#steppedJobTitle').value;
    let salaryAmountsNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.incomeSteppedJob');
    let salaryYearsNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.yearThisSteppedIncomeBegins');
    jobDataToBeReturned.salaryAmounts = [];
    jobDataToBeReturned.salaryYears = [];

    salaryAmountsNodes.forEach(e => {
        jobDataToBeReturned.salaryAmounts.push(+e.value);
    });

    salaryYearsNodes.forEach(e => {
        jobDataToBeReturned.salaryYears.push(+e.value);
    });

    return jobDataToBeReturned;
}


export function runCalculationsOnSteppedData(jobData){
    let jobDataToBeReturned = new JobDataHandler(jobData).findStepped();

    return jobDataToBeReturned;
}

function updateSteppedJobDataState(jobData, steppedJobDataState, setSteppedJobDataState){
    let extantJobs = [...steppedJobDataState];

    if (steppedJobDataState.length === 0){
        setSteppedJobDataState(jobData);
        localStorage.setItem("steppedJob", 
    } else {
        let combinedJobs = [...extantJobs, ...jobData];
        setSteppedJobDataState(combinedJobs);
        localStorage.setItem("steppedJob", 
    }
 }
```

I just tried to make a minimal version of my code to reproduce the error and share it, but unfortunately... the minimal version actually works. I have no idea why mine is broken. Here is the working minimal version:

```
import './App.css';
import {useState} from "react";

function handleState(setJobState, jobState) {

  let array = [{
    jobTitle: "Random",
    key: 0,
    pass: true,
    salaryAmounts: [123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123],
    salarySumByYear: [123, 246, 369, 492, 615, 738, 861, 984, 1107, 1230, 1353, 1476, 1599, 1722, 1845],
    salaryYears: [1],
    sum: 1845,
    yearsNumbered: ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6', 'Year 7', 'Year 8', 'Year 9', 'Year 10', 'Year 11', 'Year 12', 'Year 13', 'Year 14', 'Year 15'],
  }];

  array = array.concat(jobState);

  setJobState(array);
  console.log(jobState)

}

function App() {

  const [jobState, setJobState] = useState([]);
  let x = JSON.stringify(jobState);
  console.log(x)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleState(setJobState, jobState);
        }}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you share the exact content of `steppedJobDataState`

Comment: Does `steppedJobDataState` get filled by a fetch call?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you use `setSteppedJobDataState`? It seems you are not filling the array correctly.

Comment: Console logs are not proof that the state is correct. Please add a text-based [mcve]

Comment: @Aneesh I added a picture of the full contents of the array.

Comment: @EranMachiels I added more code. For what it's worth, the script correctly renders bar charts based on the array's state. So when I took the screenshots above, I had three bar charts -- and their data matched the data in each array.

Comment: Thank you. What is the structure of the array returned from `new JobDataHandler(jobData).findStepped()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the result of cc(steppedJobDataState), each item in steppedJobDataState is an empty array with properties. It's like

```
const steppedJobDataState = []
const item = [];
item.jobTitle = 'Random';
steppedJobDataState.push(item);
const x = JSON.stringify(steppedJobDataState);
cc(x);
```

The output above must be [[]], because JSON.stringify won't stringify the properties of an array. Use Object type instead of Array to represent items in steppedJobDataState.

Comment: This exactly matches the formats I'm seeing in console log, and explains why my minimalized version of the problem with hard-coded [{key:value}] worked just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the way that you are handling your object. It is hard to provide an answer without the exact code. But if your object had data then it should print.

[image: Example of stringify on an object with data]

The fact that your objects are still returning an empty array tells me that you do not have data inside of your object. You should add loggs to the beginning and end of every function that changes the data to see how your data is handled and to ensure that you are assigning data like you expect.

Comment: It did the same thing, all I see when I log x is [] -- one of these for each array entry. But no contents inside of it.